# Rails .build assosciation not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` model as below,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
  has_many :company_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :companies, :through => :company_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :company_users
end
```

and its associated model `CompanyUser` as below,

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :role
end
```

I am trying to build the associations as below but it seems like not working

```
  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.company_users.build
  end
```

View file is as follows,

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <h3>Companies and Roles</h3>
  <div class="field">
    <% f.fields_for :company_users do |cu| %>
       <p>
         <%= cu.label :company_id %>
         <%= cu.text_field :company_id%>
         <%= cu.label :role_id %>
         <%= cu.text_field :role_id %>
         <%= cu.check_box :_destroy %>
         <%= cu.label :_destroy, 'delete' %>
        </p>
     <% end %>
    <p>
       <%= f.submit 'Add to user', :name => "add_company_user" %>
       <%= f.submit 'Delete from user', :name => "remove_company_user" %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: Can you post the errors generated.

Comment: @j-dexx well, there are no errors. I do not see the text fields in the UI. It is supposed to come if the associations are built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `=`, therefore the `fields_for` block isn't rendered to the page. Change this line

```
<% f.fields_for :company_users do |cu| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :company_users do |cu| %>
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann ... Damn, I guess i should take a nap now :P